# ng-selected not working angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<select ng-model="dayOfMonth">
   <option value="" label="Select day"></option>
   <option ng-selected="parseInt(dayOfMonth) === parseInt(day+1)"  ng-repeat="day in getTotalDays() track by $index" value="{{$index+1}}>{{$index+1 | ordinal}} of the month</option>
</select>
```

I have an ng-model `dayOfMonth` whose value i am getting as 12, but when i try to select a default value based on `dayOfMonth` its always selecting all the last index.

Below is my `getTotalDays` function which just returns an array of 28 items.

```
$scope.getTotalDays = function(){
   return new Array(28);
}
```

Comment: Theres a missing " after the value

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x0n0gous/ it does not work..

Comment: @Shane, is there a reason to not use `ngOptions` (the directive that was made exclusively for `<select>` tag)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace this:

```
<select ng-model="dayOfMonth">
   <option value="" label="Select day"></option>
   <option ng-selected="parseInt(dayOfMonth) === parseInt(day+1)"  ng-repeat="day in getTotalDays() track by $index" value="{{$index+1}}>{{$index+1 | ordinal}} of the month</option>
</select>
```

with `ng-options`  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

like so:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.getTotalDays = [1, 2, 3, 5];
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <select ng-model="dayOfMonth" ng-options="day as (day + ' of the month') for day in getTotalDays">
      <option value="" label="Select day"></option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `ng-selected` because the proper option in your `<select>` will be set by `ng-model`. One possible issue you may have had is if you are setting `dayOfMonth = 12` since it is an int, but the option values are all strings. The below snippet works although I had to remove the `| ordinal` filter since you didn't provide that code.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.dayOfMonth = '12';
    $scope.getTotalDays = function() {
      return new Array(28);
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select ng-model="dayOfMonth">
    <option value="" label="Select day"></option>
    <option ng-repeat="day in getTotalDays() track by $index" value="{{$index+1}}">{{$index+1}} of the month</option>
  </select>
</div>
```